# Error caused when using the new operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, new-operator

I am creating a browser game that uses JavaScript to control the game functionality, but after having scoured the internet, I have failed to find a solution to my weird and specific problem, especially given that the code I have is quite simple.

```
class Location {
    constructor(location, name) {
        this.location = location;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
class Storage {
    constructor(location, name) {
        this.location = location;
        this.name = name;
        this.milk = 0;
        this.milkinc = 1;
        this.pickles = 0;
        this.pickleinc = 1;
    }
}

var garden = new Location("map-garden", "Garden");
var house = new Storage("map-home", "Home");
```

The `location` parameter here is just a reference for its position as a block in my main HTML code which looks something like this:

```
<div id="map-home" class="container">
    <table class="map container">
        <tr>
            <td class="buttonholder">
                <div class="button" onclick="togglewindow('map-home')"><¬</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="buttonholder">
                <div class="button" onclick="togglewindow('map-garden')">Garden</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
…
```

To avoid confusion, `<¬` has no syntax in the code, it is just a string and works fine.

When I run the HTML on Microsoft Edge browser, it gives me the following error

Hmmm... cannot reach this page

Make sure that you’ve got the right web address: file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/[object%20Object]

with the details:

This website could not be found.

Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND

The name of the file should actually be main.html, rather than what is has been replaced with - [object%20Object]. This only occurs when I attempt to create a new object using the `new` operator in my JavaScript code. On IE Explorer, the webpage loads, however all JavaScript code after the first line with `new` is not compiled and read by the HTML code.

I have tried resolving this issue by trying to use different methods of making classes, for example using `function`, but that has only yielded the same error. Again, I think this is rather strange given how simple the code is, but as I have not used the `new` operator before, I wondered if there was anyone with much more experience than me that could help to resolve this issue.

Comment: I think `Location` is used for some other purpose in JS. Try using another name.

Comment: @user202729 I tried changing `Location` but the problem persisted. But, when I changed `location` (with the lower case l) it seemed to work. It would be great if you could post this as an answer in the event others fall upon the same error. Thanks!

Comment: The best way to avoid clashes with the very crowded global namespace in the browser context is to isolate all your code inside a big anonymous function.

Comment: don't use `location` it is short for `window.location` and could change the page to a 404 if you set it to something weird - in your case this.location is not window.location but I recommend you use loc or similar

Comment: Although this seems to be an Edge bug, it's a variable name so it should not change global variable. Tested on another browser and it works fine.

Comment: Just tested on Microsoft Edge (can't reproduce) and IE (syntax error with `class`) Which version are you using?